# How can I replace specific instances of a character in a string using regexp?

Tags: regex

I'm programming in perl, but I believe this is just a general regexp question...

I have this string ....    `12.34.56_aa.bb.cc`

I want this............    `123456_aa.bb.cc`

IOW, I want to replace just the instances of `.` that reside between the ints.

Comment: Use lookarounds to match `.` that has a digit before and after it.

Comment: And replace it with an empty string. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for how to use lookarounds in regexp.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all dots preceded and followed by a digit (using a lookahead and a lookbehind) with an empty string.

```perl
$str = "12.34.56_aa.bb.cc";

$str =~ s/(?<=[0-9])\.(?=[0-9])//g;

print $str;
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@luKRIwVZBydBIz9hEz9QsPjFRLylJLzlZyZqLCyJZp1Csr2FvYxttoGsZqxmjp2EPZerrpwMVFRRl5pUogJRa//8PAA)

Comment: Or just `s/(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)//g`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need lookaheads or lookbehinds. You can just use a simple capturing group pattern that matches a dot `.` between two digits `\d`.

```perl
my $input_string = "12.34.56_aa.bb.cc";
$input_string =~ s/(\d)\.(\d)/$1$2/g;
print $input_string; # Output: "123456_aa.bb.cc"
```

Uses capturing groups `(\d)` to match integers on either side of the dot. The `\.` matches the dot character literally.

Use `$1` and `$2` to refer to the captured digits. Use `$1$2` in the replacement part of the `s///` operator to remove the dot between the integers.

Comment: How about [a string like `1.2.3_aa.bb.cc`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UkElM6@gtCS@uKQoMy9dwVZByVDPSM84PjFRLylJLzlZyZoLTUWdQrG@RkyKZoweiNRXMVQx0k@35ioAypagmmb9/z8A)? I guess this needs improvement.

Comment: You are right. I was assuming too much. I thought numbers would always be at least double digits, but that was never mentioned. I will keep my answer incase it helps someone

Comment: You should not retain an incorrect answer. It could be misleading to someone who does not read the comments and from a personal perspective it is a magnet for downvotes.

Comment: It's not incorrect unless the OP clarifies that this could potentially be the sort of input that we're dealing with. If the OP is only working with input that contains double-digit (or more) numbers, this is the more efficient solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am keeping my answer here, because it is correct for the question that was asked. If the question is modified with new information that makes my answer wrong, then I will gladly delete it. But then you should have issue with an edit that changes the question.